# telnetlib | read all message when I have to click space if do it mannually

Tags: python, unix, telnetlib

As you know, sometimes, you have to click space to get the next page under telnet connections, unix. For instance, you 'more' a text file. You can't get all the content at one time. Using 'space' can get to the next page.

Here is the problem, what should I do when using telnetlib, python? I have to get all the information. Posting codes here would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `more(1)` or `less(1)` to view a file, use `cat(1)`. It will not perform any pagination tasks and will write all the content of the file to the terminal, raw.

Comment: Thanks. But 'more' is just for instance. I was using 'dis cur' to view configurations on a router. Any solutions?